# Confusion about a "scalable" metric

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm reading a book called [Geometry of quantum states](https://chaos.if.uj.edu.pl/~karol/geometry.htm). On page 18 the authors introduce the usual notion of metric on a vector space and continue to discuss *Minkowski distance*.

A metric $d$ on a vector space $V$ is called a Minkowski distance if
$$
\lambda d(x,y) = d(\lambda x, \lambda y)
$$
for all positive reals $\lambda$.

According to the Authors, an easy consequence of the definition is that for any $x, y \in V$ and any convex combination $z$ of $x$ and $y$, we have
$$
d(x,y) = d(x,z) + d(z, y).
$$
I spent some time trying to prove this. This is indeed trivial if the metric is induced by a norm, but I failed to prove this in general.

Now I suspect that either I have overlooked something in the definition, or the author's have slipped here, since the metric $d(x,y) = |x| + |y|$ for $x \neq y$ and $d(x,y) = 0$ for $x = y$ on $\mathbb{R}$ seems to be a Minkowski distance, but it doesn't seem to satisfy the second equation above.

Is anyone familiar with this topic?

Comment: If you also had $d(x+v, y+v)=d(x, y)$(as in [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance)) you could prove it as well.

Comment: Yeah, that affine property should probably be included in the definition.